Black screen during more 120 sec after login - link to Xorg update?
I'm on Ubuntu 22.04, my config files are fine, all works well before few days.
I have do update of software's and kernel, and I have a problem : After choosing an user and login, I have a black screen with my cursor (I can move my cursor), it is staying more than 2 minutes and after my desktop and wallpaper correctly start.
I'm on 6.5.0-41-generic, I try with an old 6.5.0-25-generic and it is the same.
I think it can be link to a new display driver, but I think the "old" kernel have an "old" one. And it is not work better.
I try to repair all of the existing error (before the upgrade) of dmesg and other log, and it is the same.
I have no error but this black screen, and probably a timeout save me !
I have test Gnome, Ubuntu, Cinnamon it is the same. I have tested on X11/Xorg and Wayland.
With Wayland it is a blackscreen with the blinking cursor, before the timeout, and all work well after.
It is the same with Lightdm and Gdm

Can we change the timeout ? I change init service timeout, it don't change my bug.

How work the boot ?
Lightdm start, and direct start Xorg after login completed ?
I have no log during the black period, just the syslog with the sys task, no dmesg error ... And nothing after the real start tell an error or anything.

Can I configure Xorg or anything else to be more verbose ?


I think it is link to Xorg update, but can be a firmware update problem to.
I have change Xorg option, uninstall mesa, but I can't blacklist the i915 driver, it always start.
I think the first step is to see more log or to disable login sequence.
I have a gen 11 i5 with i915 laptop.
Thanks in advance
